# fabricjs nodejs toSVG wrongText positioning

Tags: fabricjs

I try to use **fabricjs**  on a **node** server to create svgs. 
My problem is that the **toSVG()** function of the canvas does not recognize the fonts correctly and it calculates the character positions according to the wrong font.

used Versions:

Node: 6.10

```
"canvas": "1.6.5"
"fabric": "1.7.14"
```

AFAIK: Newer '1.7.*' versions of  fabric, also do not calculate the positions correctly.

It is working for PNGs according to the tutorial (fabric-intro-part-4).

```
canvas.contextContainer.addFont(font);
canvas.contextTop.addFont(font);
```

To generate PNG or SVG:

```
canvas.toDataURL({
  format: 'png',
});
canvas.toSVG();
```

And the PNG output is correctly positioned (see example), but using *toSVG()* does not apply the (custom) fonts correctly.

In the example you can see that custom fonts are not displayed correctly (the correct font is used for display, because the fonts are installed on my current system, but not on the node server that creates the SVG!)

My next option is to compare source code of `toDataURL(...)` and IText `toSVG()`, but I am not sure whether that will help in any way.

Since the function to generate the SVG is executed in AWS Lambda I can not install the Fonts in the Linux OS (AFAIK).

Do you have ideas or are there any tutorials or bug reports that I have missed? 
Is there anything like *contextTop* or *contextContainer*, where I can add custom fonts, so they are  applied in the `toSVG()` function?

I am thankful for any suggestions.

Example: 
[Ilustration of the Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jastQ.png)

PS: In the browser `toSvg()` knows the fonts because the browser loads them, therefore the positioning is correct!

Also asked in:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fabricjs/mff7Pr4fkGY

Bug- report: 
https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/4355

Reproduction example: 
https://github.com/willKo/BugTest

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for any software to position properly font glyphs without access to the target font files. Each font has different metrics and positioning rules, which are described in very complex opentype tables that are part of the font files themselves.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. 
The fonts are embedded in the deployment container as _.ttf_ files. 
The AWS function has access to these TrueType Definition- files and also registers them correctly within fabrics.
Using the `canvas.toDataURL({...});` function the characters have the  correct postioning in the png. 
Unfortunately the `toSVG()` method does somehow not use the added fonts.

Comment: Then unfortunately I have no more ideas. SVG in general suffers from many half-baked implementations, due to the long Microsoft boycott of this format. It is getting better nowadays and old bugs are getting fixed but one needs to be careful.

Answer (score 0):

So far Including the fonts worked. 
See

https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/4355

or example at

https://github.com/willKo/BugTest/tree/includeFontsInDOM

Unfortunately the positioning is still not correct. 
Might be connected to node-canvas.